# Code autocompletion failed in Jupyterlab on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, jupyter-lab

I notice code autocompletion is not working on my jupyterlab, but it works on my Jupyter Notebook.

Simple code like `pd.read_` and press `<tab>` but nothing happens on jupyterlab. I expect intellisense pop up and I can choose from list of `read_csv` or `read_excel` etc.

And, when I type an open bracket `(`, the cell doesn't create an autocomplete end bracket `)`.

I install Python via https://www.python.org/downloads/ and install on my company Windows laptop.

What could goes wrong? Do I need to install any library?

Comment: You don't need to install any extra library to get simple tab completion, but you might have an outdated version of one of the relevant libraries installed; for example you may have too old IPython for given jedi version 1) What is the output of `jupyter --version`? 2) What Python version do you use? 3) Are there any errors in the terminal when you start JupyterLab 4) Do you have any JupyterLab extensions installed?

Comment: @krassowski here are output of the commands: [1] jupyter version >> `jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.4.2
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.26.0
ipykernel        : 6.0.3
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.1.4
nbconvert        : 6.1.0
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5`  [2]. Python Version >> 3.9.6  [3] I think these are considered warning rather than error `Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs`. [4] I haven't install any extension.

Comment: As for the opening bracket completion, this is a change in JupyterLab 3.1 and can be re-enabled from topbar menu (Settings -> Auto Close brackets).

Comment: I guess that you could try to update `jedi` version with `pip install -U jedi`, but this does not sound like any problem I encountered before - sorry! Though you could check out jupyterlab-lsp for a completion without kernel.

Comment: @krassowski ok, i enable the `Auto Close Brackets` setting and the brackets appear automatically. Then I install Nodejs for Windows with NVS. Now the code autocompletion  and auto close brackets work. TQ.